# Subgroup of symmetries of a rectangle

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

How would I go about solving the following:

**Find all subgroups of the group of symmetries of a non square rectangle, and show that all its subgroups are in your list.**

Am I correct in saying there are 4 symmetries here: horizontal reflection, vertical reflection, identidy, 180 degrees rotation? I don't know how to proceed from there.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there are only two groups of order $4$. One has an element of order $4$ and the other does not. Which of these is your group?

Comment: @Bungo This group does not have an element of order 4. I has order 1, whilst R, H and V have order 2. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$, also known as the [Klein 4-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)

Comment: @Bungo Ah, we haven't covered isomorphism yet. I'm a bit confused at how I find the subgroups; do I just have to test if each combination of the symmetries, like the group of I and H, are groups using the criteria of a group?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem tells us that the only possible orders of subgroups are $1$, $2$, and $4$. Obviously the only subgroup of order $1$ is the trivial group, and the only subgroup of order $4$ is the entire group. For a subgroup of order $2$, you can take any element of order $2$ along with the identity. These are the only possibilities.

Comment: @Bungo Gotcha! Lastly, what does it mean in the question when it says to show that all its subgroups are in my list? My list of what?

Comment: I think it means that you should show that you have found all of the subgroups, i.e. there aren't any that you missed.